# Check if the data in a database is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm fetching the data from the database and I would like to check the data above of the data in the same rows as the per channel to see if the cell is empty.

Here is for example table:

```
---------------------------
| channel   | program_id
---------------------------
| ITV       |
| ITV       | 3021
| ITV       | 3022
| ITV       | 3023
```

Here is the code:

```
def update_in_database(self):
     profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
     conn = database.connect(profilePath)
     cur = conn.cursor()
     program_id = ''.join(str(x) for x in self.program_id)
     cur.execute('SELECT channel, program_id FROM programs WHERE program_id=?;', (program_id,))
     data = cur.fetchone()


     if data:
       #check if the data in a database is empty
```

Here is the output for the data:

```
(u'103 ITV', u'3021')
```

I have got a string of program_id which it is `3021`, so I want to check the string in a database to see if the data above of the `3021` is empty so I could do something.

How I can check in a database to see if the data above of the string is empty or not?

Comment: @Mark It appears to be using DBAPI compatible stuff and it may well be that the "do stuff" can't/isn't suitably done via pure SQL and Python can be used... if we had more info though...

Comment: @CoryMadden I have updated my question so I hope someone will be able to post the answer

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a program_id and you want to know whether the row above the given program_id is empty?

Comment: SQL tables are unordered; there is no "above".

Comment: yes there is a null above of the row where the string `3021` are so you are wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases and SQL are not really designed to be used in this way. When using a database you should not have to fetch a given row above another row.

I would advise you to change the design of your database. This will solve your problem and will make it probably easier to work with the database.

If you can given more information on all the data that needs to be saved in the database I can help you to make a better design.